# Are there any epiphytic plants that pull water from the air and supply terrestrial plants with excess?

Tags: botany

Do you know of any epiphytic plants that pull water from the air and supply the excess to other terrestrial plants?

Comment: This isn't worthy of an answer but offhand I would HIGHLY doubt it. Pulling water from the air is harder than getting it from the ground; epiphytic plants are typically the type of plant that can survive on comparatively little water for that reason. I honestly don't see a circumstance where a terrestrial plant would need water from them, and where they could afford to spare the extra (but it's been awhile since I studied plants, so could be wrong).